# Spin of a gauge field

Tags: special-relativity, mass, quantum-spin, representation-theory, lorentz-symmetry

I was wondering what is the simplest way to understand the reduction of the Wigner's little group from $SO(d-1)$ to $SO(d-2)$ when one considers massive and massless fields respectively (in a $d$ dimensional spacetime). I would like a way to see this in the equations of motion. For example a spin one matter field denoted by $C_{\mu}$ can be described by $SO(d-1)$ little group. Let's now identify $C_\mu$ and $C_{\mu} +\partial_{\mu} \epsilon $ ($\epsilon$ the gauge parameter) as physically indistinguishable. How does that reduce the little group to $SO(d-2)$.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are familiar with [Wigner's classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_classification) in *d*=4, as you might be implying. The m→0 limit is best appreciated on the [Poincaré sphere](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.4539), but let us skip that here to count particle states.

So, reviewing Wigner, for a massive state, we can Lorentz-transform the momentum to the rest frame, (m,0,0,0) so the little group is SO(3) and its vector rep is a triplet, so spin 1, and in *d*-dimensions the vector of SO(*d*-1), the spin classification being pointless.

For vanishing mass, there is no rest frame: the best we can do is (p,0,0,p), cf. [parabolic Lorentz transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group#Parabolic) , [and further](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.63.348), 
for instance, so the little group is SO(2), (actually, E(2)), and the invariant segues to the [helicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli%E2%80%93Lubanski_pseudovector). The eqns of motion are the same as before, except the absence of the mass term allows gauge invariance: with the emergence of gauge invariance, the massive triplet vector loses its gauge state, and reduces to a massless doublet. For *d* you have the vector of SO(*d*-2), again, its massive brother minus one (gauge) state.

Note how this works for the symmetric traceless tensor rep; you have *(d-1)d*/2 -1=*(d-2)(d+1)*/2 components for non-vanishing mass, so a spin two quintet for *d*=4. And *(d-2)(d-1)*/2-1 = *d(d-3)*/2  for vanishing mass, so a massless graviton doublet for *d*=4.